# Google Cloud Print with TSP100 variable length document

Tags: printing, google-cloud-print

I currently have the following issue. I would like to print a receipt (pdf file) on a Star TSP100 thermal printer with Google Cloud Print (from AppEngine). The connection works great, but I have an issue with the positioning.

The PDF file has a variable length, and therefore I have to print the document on 72mm x 2000mm (so the length is always correct). The remaining whitespace is cut off by the printer. When I print a receipt with the default print dialog in Chrome, the document is positioned at the top of the canvas (72mm x 2000mm). However, when I try to print the same document with Google Cloud Print the document is positioned at the center of the canvas. The result is a lot of whitespace before the actual receipt starts. The whitespace after is still cut off correctly by the printer.

Things I tried so far:

- Setting a specific media size in the Cloud Job Ticket (CJT). Then the printer cuts off at 200mm length (default printer setting).
- Posting a printjob from Chrome and checking the CJT of this job in the GCP Simulation API. The CJT is not different from mine, so how is Chrome able to print a different document?
- All other options in the CJT as described in the Google Cloud Print Documentation.
- Banging my head against the wall, also didn't work.

If I could mimic a request from Chrome (which gives the correct result), the problem would be solved. However, I can not see how these are different from my requests.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I'm also trying to use google cloud print, I can't find examples of use, and also I don't understand very well the documentation because is very confusing, I'm trying to make my code in javascript(side client). Do you have some document to help me?, Thanks.